# Find string matches and display them on the console screen

Tags: c#

If a match is found from the list, then the line from the list must be shown with the one that matched on the screen

```
string[] strNamesArray = { "roger", "vernie", "joel" };
if (strNamesArray.Any(x => x.Contains(ScanFile)))
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

How to output the found `strNamesArray` to the console?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
string[] strNamesArray = { "roger", "vernie", "joel" };
if (ScanFile == null) { return; } //so this could not be null
foreach (var x in strNamesArray)
{
    if(x.Contains(ScanFile))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need only linq

Comment: then rewrite your question and make it clean and clear!

you can do this with LINQ:

foreach (var x in from x in strNamesArray
                  where x.Contains(read)
                  select x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}